# Howe to show different content on page based on users subscription

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Is there any possibilities to show different content in a react component based on users subscription? 
 I would have 3 type of subscribers:

**type 1: Demo**

**type 2: Mid**

**type 3: Extra**

I have 3 mongo collections for each type of subscription.

The thing that I want to achieve is:

If Type 1 requests the API url gets data from his collection into his react component. 
If Type 2 requests the API url gets data from his collection into his react component. 
If Type 3 requests the API url gets data from his collection into his react component.

The thing to achieve this I got in my mind is to have an API endpoint in laravel. This endpoint recieves every request when a specific navbar item is clicked. That endpoint serves back the users data with details of his subscription. When I get the response with the details I send request to the specific API endpoint for data that he should see in the component and render it.

The imaginary routes are:
api/userinfo **->** to get back userdata 
api/demo **->** to get data for user with type of subscription: demo
api/mid **->** to get data for user with type of subscription: mid
api/extra **->** to get data for user with type of subscription: extra

Are there any better options to achieve this thing?
Can I do it in 1 API route and achieve this behaviour with a route middleware?

Comment: The only thing I can say (I dont think your reasoning is wrong) is that you could use just one route for all three types of subscriptions and send a parameter in your post request to say what info you look for, then based on user data(user should be logged in if not demo) and return the correct info from the db. Having less endpoints can make things easier. I wouldnt recommend all in one route as you have two totally different things, user info and website information based on user subscription. In my view these should always be kept apart, mixing them will make it harder for you in the future

Comment: Probably overthinked it a bit. But that was the first thing in my mind too. To have 1 endpoint, and on the subscription detail based from request just load the correct data and return it as a response. But the other viewpoint is that the collections are filled with diferent data and MID is changing in every minute, EXTRA is changing constantly, and to display this changes on the frontend I need to request this endpoint from the users specific component. From MID's component in every minute,from EXTRA's component every 5-10 seconds.Probably thats why I'm thinking on doing it on diferent routes.